# removing NaN from dataset

Tags: python, pandas

```
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 dataset = pd.read_csv('Data.csv')
 X = dataset.iloc[:,:-1]
 y = dataset.iloc[:, 3]

from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
imputer =Imputer(missing_values = 'NaN', strategy = 'mean' ,axis = 0)
imputer = imputer.fit(X.values[:, 1:3])
X.values[:, 1:3] = imputer.transform(X.values[:, 1:3])
```

this code is working find but not able to remove NaN from my dataset.please help.

Comment: Add link to your file...

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gRnHCNTWv1Q3N90SlhRCp4y1ADTccwHozyafjrqpqhE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: your problem is only one keyword `values` which is in wrong place. See my my answer below, it works fine. I have done the course.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for:

```
[print(X.dropna())][1]
```

?

Comment: no I want to replace NaN values into Mean of values of that column

Answer (score 0):

The `values` of a DataFrame are not mutable (not changeable), so your last line should be throwing an error because it's trying to assign to `X.values[:, 1:3]`. Instead, try assigning to the DataFrame itself using the `.loc` or `iloc` accessors:

```
X.iloc[:, 1:3] = imputer.transform(X.values[:, 1:3])
```

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
X.fillna(X.mean(axis=0), axis=0)
```

?

Answer (score -1):

First you cannot change values of `pandas dataframe`. So first of all, copy values to a numpy array like this:

```
# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('Data.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 3].values
```

Then, you can do what have you done in your code. Just remove those `values` in the last line so like this:

```
# Taking care of missing data
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
imputer = Imputer(missing_values = 'NaN', strategy = 'mean', axis = 0)
imputer = imputer.fit(X[:, 1:3])
X[:, 1:3] = imputer.transform(X[:, 1:3])
```

Comment: Also you can find full implementations of all steps in this [repository](https://github.com/Nikronic/Machine-Learning-Models).